# Postgres insert into `select distinct` view if not exists

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I have an `events` table which is a denormalized table containing `item` data. There is a one-to-many relationship between items and events.

```sql
CREATE TABLE events
(
   id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
   item VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
   created TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL...
)
```

I also have a `SELECT DISTINCT` view called `items` which essentially takes the last event row for each `item`. I would really like to be able to insert into that view as though it were a physical table, *including a constraint error* if the user-provided `item` ID already exists.

I believe I need to create a trigger function, but I'm not sure what the query would look like to return a constraint violation (or maybe some other exception that callers can catch?). I think trigger functions have to be PL/pgSQL, but ideally it would hew as closely as possible to plain SQL.

Comment: Presumably that trigger would have to insert a row into the underlying `items` table, which will obviously fail if the corresponding unique constraint is violated, so I'm not really sure what is the problem.

Comment: @mustaccio `items` isn't a table, is a view into the `events` table. Consequently there is no `unique` constraint to violate (the only unique constraint in the system is `events.id`).

Comment: Please clarify the task. Show the exact view definition and your version of Postgres. Why do you want a "constraint error" (without constraint) for duplicate user-provided item ID, while the table `events` is obviously designed to hold multiple rows per item. Why not create an actual `item` table with unique items? (Or is that an option?)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that the view is defined as

```
CREATE VIEW event_items AS SELECT DISTINCT item FROM events;
```

Writing a trigger like that is not difficult; the problem is that such triggers always suffer from race conditions with concurrent `INSERT`s.

There are only two ways to avoid race conditions:

1. Lock all affected rows to serialize operations:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION ins_trig() RETURNS trigger
      LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
   $$BEGIN
      PERFORM FROM events
      WHERE item = NEW.item
      FOR NO KEY UPDATE;

      IF FOUND THEN
         RAISE EXCEPTION unique_violation
         USING MESSAGE = 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint',
               DETAIL = format('Key (item)=(%s) already exists.', NEW.item);
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO events (id, item, created)
      VALUES (gen_random_uuid(), NEW.item, current_timestamp);

      RETURN NULL;
   END;$$;

   CREATE TRIGGER ins_trig INSTEAD OF INSERT ON event_items
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION ins_trig();
   ```
2. Set `default_transaction_isolation = 'serializable'` to use the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level throughout and remove the `FOR NO KEY UPDATE` in the above example.

   For that to work well, you need an index on `events.items`, otherwise [you'll get predicate locks on the whole table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) and very bad concurrency.

   Note that with `SERIALIZABLE` isolation you have to be prepared to get serialization errors, which require you to retry the `INSERT` until it succeeds.

See [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/triggers-to-enforce-constraints/) for some background information.